# construction of the question

Tags: sentence-construction, questions, construction

Is it correct to say like this? Or are these questions both wrong?

> Why did this sentence make differently?
>
> Why is this sentence made differently?

Comment: In your first sentence, *sentence* is the subject of the verb *make*, inviting the question: what was made? Sentences do not normally make anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this sentence made differently?

The above makes more sense than the other version of:

> Why did this sentence make differently?

This makes some sense to me - though it would never be said that way - but to me it's wrong because it sort of implies that the sentence itself has some autonomy, or that there was an inevitably coming from outside factors that resulted in the sentence ending up the way it did, suggesting that any effort would always result in the same sentence being created regardless of how one tried to direct it.

All that being said, however, the verb "make" is generally too abstract to be used when discussing the construction of a sentence, especially as this would usually be done in a formal/academic setting. Therefore, it would be better to use:

> Why is this sentence constructed differently?

Comment: What about this?: "What are these sentences called?" or
"How does called these sentences?"

Comment: "Called" is a bit too abstract to be understood. You could try, "What type of sentences are these?", or, "How would you describe the structure of these sentences?", or, "What structures are used in the construction of these sentences?"